# Filtering in table from last query ID in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The following code works fine:

```
CREATE USER test PASSWORD='test';
DESC USER test;
SELECT * from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

However when I try to only return **one** column:

```
CREATE USER test PASSWORD='test';
DESC USER test;
SELECT value from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

I get an error:

```
Error: invalid identifier 'VALUE'.
```

Why does it return this error, as value is an existing column on the result scan?

Comment: try upper case, snowflake is case sensiotive

Comment: @nbk looks like Snowflake is doing some mumbo jumbo in the background and is transforming the column names to uppercase while they are written in lower case.

Comment: Please share the result of your query as well please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use quoted identifier `"col name"` to access it:

```
SELECT value from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
=>
SELECT "value" from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

Related: [Identifier Requirements](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax)